# ls() in R produces the same output

Tags: r

`ls()` produces the same output, wherever the path is; even when I change the working directory with `setwd()` the output is always the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read `?ls`. The very first sentence tells us that the purpose of `ls` is not what you are assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls()` lists objects inside R, you need `list.files()` for listing files, which seems to be what you're after

Answer (score 2):

Look at the help page (`?ls`):

> ‘ls’ and ‘objects’ return a vector of character strings giving the
>        names of the objects in the specified environment.

"Environment" refers to the R process. Essentially, `ls()` gives you the variables R knows at this moment.

If you are looking for directory listings, use `list.files()`.